# Comma between operators in C++

Tags: c++, overloading

Today I came across this piece of code (inside  *boost/type_index/type_index_facade.hpp*, lines 252-259).

```
/// noexcept comparison operators for type_index_facade classes.
bool operator ==, !=, <, ... (const type_index_facade& lhs, const type_index_facade& rhs) noexcept;

/// noexcept comparison operators for type_index_facade and it's TypeInfo classes.
bool operator ==, !=, <, ... (const type_index_facade& lhs, const TypeInfo& rhs) noexcept;

/// noexcept comparison operators for type_index_facade's TypeInfo and type_index_facade classes.
bool operator ==, !=, <, ... (const TypeInfo& lhs, const type_index_facade& rhs) noexcept;
```

Can someone explain me what does it mean? I have never seen before something like "==, !=, <, ..."

Comment: I don't know what it is but isn't C++.

Comment: @101010 it is C++11

Comment: @FirstStep this is not valid C++11,  as explained by the top answer

Comment: @FirstStep: It certainly is not.

Answer (score 31):

You'll notice that these are written within:

```
#if defined(BOOST_TYPE_INDEX_DOXYGEN_INVOKED)
    ...
#endif
```

This is just a hack to make doxygen use these "simplified" declarations in the documentation.  This bit of the code is never compiled.